# Display div based on user age

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

I want to display certain DIVs to certain users. To do that I have a column in phpMyAdmin, called "UserType" which indicates if the user is above or below 18. Based on that, if the user is below 18, I want to hide all DIVs with ID "18+". Here's an example of two different DIVs that contain products:

```html
<div id="18+" class="content">
  <a href= "pulpfiction.html"><img src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
  <p>Pulp Fiction</p>
  <p>£8.90</p>
  <hr>
</div>

<div id="13+" class="content">
  <a href= "blueexorcist.html"><img src="img/blueexorcist.jpg" style="width:100%;"></a>
  <p>Blue Exorcist</p>
  <p>£8.90</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

What I'm trying now is:

```
    <?php
$userQuery = mysqli_query($con, $sql="SELECT UserType FROM users;");
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery); //gets user data as an array
?>

<script>
function toggleDivAdult(){
    var x = document.getElementById("13+");
    var y = document.getElementById("18+");
    if ($user['UserType'] == 'M') { x.style.display = "none"; }
    else if ($user['UserType'] == 'C') { y.style.display = "none"; }
</script>
```

'M' means mature user and 'C' means child

Comment: You can use `style="display: none;"` in the div side. Using jQuery, you can read the column value and execute `.show()` or `hide()`

Comment: I would do this on the server side otherwise underage users will still have access to the other content if they run developer tools and unhide the divs - ie don't use js or css to hide age restricted content, make sure the content is never output to the DOM in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Considering you are using phpMyAdmin and SQL, I would recommend you use PHP to decide which div is printed to the page.

Example:

```
<?php
$c = ; //your sql connection
$userQuery = mysqli_query($c, /* your query for the user */);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery); //gets user data as an array
if ($user['UserType'] == '18+') { ?>
<div ...></div>
<? }
else if ($user['UserType'] == '13+') { ?>
<div ...></div>
<? }
else { /* otherwise */ }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it all does make sense, however, I can't seem to put it to work. I have edited the post to show you what I'm trying out

Comment: That's because you're trying to reference the PHP data in JavaScript. Another thing, don't use PHP to show/hide the divs; users will still be able to see it using developer tools. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

i just add ".adult" class and check it

The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".content"), (el) =>
{
    if (el.classList.contains("adult"))
    {
        el.style.display = "none";
    }

})
```

```html
<div id="18+" class="content adult">
  <a href= "pulpfiction.html"><img src="img/2.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
  <p>Pulp Fiction</p>
  <p>£8.90</p>
  <hr>
</div>

<div id="13+" class="content">
  <a href= "blueexorcist.html"><img src="img/blueexorcist.jpg" style="width:100%;"></a>
  <p>Blue Exorcist</p>
  <p>£8.90</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit green in coding, is the first one you posted a JavaScript function?

Comment: now all element with adult in class will be disable